# Python: search - in nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to search '-' in my nested list that contains a nested dictionary. I have also tried the below solution but it didn't work.

**List Output:**

```
[[[[50.0, 23.0], [196.0, 23.0], [196.0, 46.0], [50.0, 46.0]], ('주민등록층', 0.8442377)], [[[95.0, 51.0], [154.0, 51.0], [154.0, 65.0], [95.0, 65.0]], ('재외국민', 0.857541)], [[[59.0, 75.0], [118.0, 75.0], [118.0, 95.0], [59.0, 95.0]], ('이영희', 0.92137283)], [[[59.0, 105.0], [197.0, 105.0], [197.0, 121.0], [59.0, 121.0]], ('470315-9428744', 0.96879905)], [[[46.0, 126.0], [144.0, 129.0], [143.0, 146.0], [46.0, 142.0]], ('전라묵도 흥천군', 0.71075964)], [[[48.0, 144.0], [130.0, 144.0], [130.0, 158.0], [48.0, 158.0]], ('각남대요거리는', 0.73041165)], [[[45.0, 160.0], [144.0, 160.0], [144.0, 173.0], [45.0, 173.0]], ('설현말미마를 ', 0.74398714)], [[[132.0, 180.0], [220.0, 179.0], [220.0, 194.0], [132.0, 195.0]], ('-20210908', 0.79617107)], [[[112.0, 199.0], [281.0, 200.0], [281.0, 217.0], [112.0, 216.0]], ('부산특별시 무산구청정', 0.8322405)]]
```

**Code:**

```
var = '-' in (y for x in result for y in x)
        print(var)
```

**Final Output**

[image]

Comment: So you just want it it to print the values with `-` in them. Not to return a (nested) index of the location of the string?

Comment: I just want to print the complete value of '-' with their coordinates, so that I can draw the rectangle on it

Comment: Can you include your expected output in the question?

Comment: Your list does not contain any dictionaries.

Comment: @PaulRooney Ok I am including it please give me 5 minutes.

Comment: @DYZ my mistake sorry

Comment: @j1-lee this is a demo, I am using OCR to detect characters and make them like this. Yes location of the box which contains '-' thing

Comment: are we supposed to produce the image as output?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is a good case

Comment: @j1-lee the expected output in picture first detected the card number with coordinate and then draw the rectangle to hide the number

Comment: @j1-lee, Sorry, I am also confused. The picture is expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As you change your question. I change the solution to provide position info.

```
test_list = [
    [
        [[50.0, 23.0], [196.0, 23.0], [196.0, 46.0], [50.0, 46.0]],
        ("주민등록층", 0.8442377),
    ],
    [
        [[95.0, 51.0], [154.0, 51.0], [154.0, 65.0], [95.0, 65.0]],
        ("재외국민", 0.857541),
    ],
    [
        [[59.0, 75.0], [118.0, 75.0], [118.0, 95.0], [59.0, 95.0]],
        ("이영희", 0.92137283),
    ],
    [
        [[59.0, 105.0], [197.0, 105.0], [197.0, 121.0], [59.0, 121.0]],
        ("470315-9428744", 0.96879905),
    ],
    [
        [[46.0, 126.0], [144.0, 129.0], [143.0, 146.0], [46.0, 142.0]],
        ("전라묵도 흥천군", 0.71075964),
    ],
    [
        [[48.0, 144.0], [130.0, 144.0], [130.0, 158.0], [48.0, 158.0]],
        ("각남대요거리는", 0.73041165),
    ],
    [
        [[45.0, 160.0], [144.0, 160.0], [144.0, 173.0], [45.0, 173.0]],
        ("설현말미마를 ", 0.74398714),
    ],
    [
        [[132.0, 180.0], [220.0, 179.0], [220.0, 194.0], [132.0, 195.0]],
        ("-20210908", 0.79617107),
    ],
    [
        [[112.0, 199.0], [281.0, 200.0], [281.0, 217.0], [112.0, 216.0]],
        ("부산특별시 무산구청정", 0.8322405),
    ],
]
positions = []
text_infos = []
for line in test_list:
    position = line[0]
    text_info = line[1]
    if "-" in text_info[0]:
        print(f"position: {position}")
        print(f"text_info: {text_info}")
        positions.append(position)
        text_infos.append(text_info)

print(f"positions: {positions}")
print(f"text_infos: {text_infos}")
```

Comment: How to get along with coordinates?

Comment: If you want to draw polygons on an existed image. I suggest using pillow. You can search some tutorial about pillow. Then use pillow modify your image

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
llist = [[[[50.0, 23.0], [196.0, 23.0], [196.0, 46.0], [50.0, 46.0]], ('주민등록층', 0.8442377)], [[[95.0, 51.0], [154.0, 51.0], [154.0, 65.0], [95.0, 65.0]], ('재외국민', 0.857541)], [[[59.0, 75.0], [118.0, 75.0], [118.0, 95.0], [59.0, 95.0]], ('이영희', 0.92137283)], [[[59.0, 105.0], [197.0, 105.0], [197.0, 121.0], [59.0, 121.0]], ('470315-9428744', 0.96879905)], [[[46.0, 126.0], [144.0, 129.0], [143.0, 146.0], [46.0, 142.0]], ('전라묵도 흥천군', 0.71075964)], [[[48.0, 144.0], [130.0, 144.0], [130.0, 158.0], [48.0, 158.0]], ('각남대요거리는', 0.73041165)], [[[45.0, 160.0], [144.0, 160.0], [144.0, 173.0], [45.0, 173.0]], ('설현말미마를 ', 0.74398714)], [[[132.0, 180.0], [220.0, 179.0], [220.0, 194.0], [132.0, 195.0]], ('-20210908', 0.79617107)], [[[112.0, 199.0], [281.0, 200.0], [281.0, 217.0], [112.0, 216.0]], ('부산특별시 무산구청정', 0.8322405)]]

for x in llist:
    for item1 in x[0]:
        for item1_1 in item1:
            if '-' in str(item1_1):
                print(item1_1)
    for item2 in x[1]:
        if '-' in str(item2):
            print(item2)
```

It has more simpler logic and it is according to your dataset.

Comment: How to get along with coordinates?

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Please check the picture, this is my expected output. Now, I have a list of detected elements with coordinates. I want to check that if it contains '-' then I will draw a rectangle and fill it with colors.